# WordPress localisation of german date string

Tags: php, wordpress, localization

Hi @ll and greetings from Germany,

Perhaps I am too blind to see, but I am struggling with a localisation problem. I hope that someone has a solution for that.

In a function I have a german date string, assume it's today:

```
$datestring = '3. März 2014'
```

Second, i have the date format used in WP

```
$date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
```

What I am trying to achive is to get a valid unix timestamp from $datestring.

I tried several different approaches like strtotime, date_parse_from_format, etc., I even tried to set the locale environment via setlocale. Of course it would be easy to parse the string against an array with the month names and get an english datestring, but I want to have this ready for all languages.

Any Idea how to get this done? Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mktime($datestring)
and set the $datestring variable in accordance to:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php
in wordpress:

```
   mktime(get_the_date("H"), get_the_date("i"), get_the_date("s"), get_the_date("n"), get_the_date("j"), get_the_date("Y"));
```

if you need to convert exact format shown above:

```
   $datestring = '3. März 2014';
   $dateelements = explode(" ", $datestring);
   $day = rtrim($dateelements[0], ".");
   $germanMonths = array(1 =>  "Januar", 2 => "Februar", 3 => "März", 4 => "April", 5 => "Mai", 6 => "Juni", 7 => "Juli", 8 => "August", 9 => "September", 10 => "Oktober " , 11 => "November", 12 => "Dezember");
   $month = array_search($dateelements[1], $germanMonths);
   $year = $dateelements[2];
   $unixtimestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
```

and if you have a date format in wp option, and $datestring is in that format:

```
   $dateformat =  get_option('date_format');
   echo $dateformat;
   $date = date_create_from_format($dateformat, $datestring);
   $new_format = date_format($date, 'm,d,Y');
   $unixtimestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$new_format);
   echo $unixtimestamp;
```

Comment: Getting the $datestring formated as needed is exactly the problem. Since I need it for a theme framework, it should be generated somewhat automatically. I allready stumbled across $wp_locale->month, which has an array of the month names in it. But I have no idea how to make use of them.

The key to succes must be the $date_format, which somehow should tell me which part of $datestring is month, day and year *sigh*

Comment: The function get_the_date always fetches the date of a post, so that is of no use for me. Here's the scenario: I have a custom post type with a custom metabox added. In this metabox is a date selector. For conveniant use, I want to handle the field input as a natural string, so it stays readable on first sight. What I now want to achieve, is to store the value of that field, which can obvious be any date and is not conjuncted to the post date, into the database as either a) a time stamp or b) a MySQL date, so I can make use of it in my theme frontend. Do you have an Idea about this scenario?

Comment: OK. Understood. By handling input as a string you mean data is validated on browser side, and is always formatted as in your question? If yes, see edit above. If not always formated this way, I would rather recommend use on input side some tool like http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: And exactly there lies the trap. Works like a charm, if the date is german. But what if a user uses another language? So the only chance to get this dynamic is to parse the date format (j. F Y in my case) to create a valid timestamp. I allready use the built in WP datepicker. I of course could use d\m\y or similar as input mask during datepicker initialisation, but I'd rather prefer to solve this problem in general. By the way, thank you for your effort so far!

Comment: Your question was "...german...", so anyways, if the date can be typed manually, number of possible combinations is almost infinite. Do we know at least the language?

Comment: Yes, of course we have the locale, you can allways get it via get_locale(). And we know the exact date format as well.

Comment: $wp_locale->month contains an array with the month names in the current language

Comment: Hope now is what you needed :)